# HP Pavilion 11-n038ca touchscreen

Tags: laptop, hp, touchscreen, hp-pavilion

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a HP Pavilion 11-n038ca laptop, but the touchscreen is not working. Can anyone tell me how to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/452159/ubuntu-14-04-multi-touch-screen-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug wich is fixed in the upstream kernel version 3.17-rc7. More details about this can be found at the bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1376509