# Ubuntu 14.04 Laptop Screen Shaking - no problem on external monitor (HDMI) - Lenovo Y70 Touch

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, screen, intel

I've just got a Lenovo Y70 Touch laptop.

Problem: The laptop screen is vibrating, (flickering? shaking? not sure what the best word for it) as if refresh rate was the problem. (17.3" 1920x1080) External monitor through HDMI working OK, no problem.

The problem started from the very beginning, when I booted from the Ubuntu 14.04 DVD.

No problems under Windows 7 and 8.1.

Comment: Disabling the kernel module for the intel driver solved the flicker-problem, but produced two more problems: 1. BRIGHTNESS CANNOT BE ADJUSTED, 2. THE LAPTOP IS GETTING HOT

Comment: Why is it ok on an external monitor and why is not ok on the laptop screen?

Comment: Could it be the touch module?  Does it register as a mouse or touchpad perhaps?

Comment: Could you please tell me what to look at?

Comment: I got this for xinput:  Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller id=11 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad               id=15 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:1017 id=16 [slave  pointer  (2)]

Comment: Apparently it works for some models http://askubuntu.com/questions/452159/ubuntu-14-04-multi-touch-screen-support

Comment: @JNE: Please [edit] your question if you have something to add. It's much more difficult to find all the relevant info scattered in the comments. This way you can also keep the line breaks of program output and log files.

Comment: I have the same problem, Linux Mint 17.1, based on Ubuntu 14.4. Lenovo Y70 (17.3''). Windows work fine, just as for you. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with you, after numerous installs I could not fix the issue, but then i tried installing a later kernel, more specific 3.18rc3. For me this fixed the problem, the one thing that i can not do is install the nvidia drivers but this is not an issue for me.

Get the .deb files from here http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-kernel-3-18-rc3-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-and-derivatives/

I hope this helps

Comment: Upgrading to kernel 3.18 solved the problem for me too! Thanks. Why did someone downvote this answer??? Upvoted. (Neither kernel 3.13 nor 3.16 worked.)