# Ubuntu shaky display problem

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, elementary, crunchbang

Good afternoon, I recently got the lenovo y70 touch laptop and got it ready for Linux, however, Ubuntu has a display problem where the screen looks like it's shaking or tearing, I've tried nvidia drivers to no avail. The strange thing is that on distros that don't support touch out of the box like crunchbang and elementary OS don't have this issue, but have a lot less out of the box features compared to Ubuntu so I'd rather use Ubuntu. Any ideas?

Comment: This might be due to the issue with Graphic Card. Try by re-installing it and check whether the shaky dsplay will goes off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to kernel 3.18 — or 3.19, see below —, that solved the problem for me.

I have a Lenovo Y70, like you. And Linux Mint 17.1 which is based on Ubuntu 14.04. Installing the latest NVIDIA drivers had no effect, only upgrading to kernel 3.18 worked. Kernel 3.16 didn't work.

Unfortunately, my wireless network card doesn't work with 3.18 :-(  So I just installed kernel 3.19. That one seems to have solved both the shaky display issue, and works with the Y70 wireless network card. So the fourth kernel I tested worked :-) Last time, with Linux Mint 17, I had to try 3 different kernels before the network card was happy.

This is how I installed 3.19. Perhaps you'd need to use other URLs if new patch versions have been released.

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19-vivid/linux-headers-3.19.0-031900-generic_3.19.0-031900.201502091451_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19-vivid/linux-headers-3.19.0-031900_3.19.0-031900.201502091451_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19-vivid/linux-image-3.19.0-031900-generic_3.19.0-031900.201502091451_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.19.*  linux-image-3.19.*.deb
sudo update-grub  # not needed?
sudo reboot now
```

Comment: Is your two finger scroll working? I've tried a lot of kernels and that seems to be another issue besides the wireless card. Will try the kernel you're using now!

Comment: Everything is working perfectly, marked as solved for anyone else that's still having this issue.

Comment: @HurricaneChris Yes two finger scrolling works for me with 3.19. (Don't remember if it worked with 3.13, 3.16 and 3.18.) (That is, I can scroll horizontally and vertically by dragging two fingers on the touchpad.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the display is not the problem. Maybe it is the input device which is part of the screen the Nvidia drivers are rendering to. Check the HID devices which might be present for your touch screen to provide system input. Or, check which ones should be present, anyway, and make sure they are. If you have a mouse and a track pad and a keyboard joystick and a touch screen, try disabling them all, and enabling one at a time to see if they are interfering with each other.

Comment: How would I go about checking and removing those, I've never messed with that before.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/531897/ubuntu-14-04-laptop-screen-shaking-no-problem-on-external-monitor-hdmi-len, actually.  They just upgraded their machine, and that seemed to fix the problem.  To unload drivers, find the driver name from `sudo lsmod`, and then type `sudo rmmod [modulename]`.  That other question mentioned the "intel" module.  To fully update in the console, type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and answer yes when appropriate.

Comment: I've tried updating the kernel as well but not to that specific version, I'll try that and get back to you, thanks!